# Getting ID of control when using Editor template

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Till now I've had a view and a controller. In my view I've used `Html.IdFor` when I needed the ID in a script.

However, after adding editor templates the Html.IdFor doesn't work (obviously).

**So my question**: What is the best way to refer controls when using an editor template? I could add a unique class or give it some obscure ID, but it just doesn't feel very generic compared to the Html.IdFor solution.

View script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#doHaveAddress').change(function () {
            $('#plcBitcoinAddress').toggle();
        });

        $('#@Html.IdFor(m => m.PurchaseViewModel.PurchaseAmount)').keyup(function () {
            updateSummary();
        });

        //$('#submitBtn').click(function() {
        //    window.location.href = "/en/orders/25892e17-80f6-415f-9c65-7395632f0223";
        //});

        updateSummary();
    });

    function updateSummary() {
        var purchaseAmount = $('#@Html.IdFor(m => m.PurchaseViewModel.PurchaseAmount)').val();
        var bitcoinRate = '@Helper.GetBitcoinCurrencyRate(Currency.dkk)';

        // set amount
        $('#summary_purchaseamount').text(purchaseAmount);

        // set fee
        var fee = (('@Helper.SiteFee()') / 100) * purchaseAmount;
        $('#summary_fee').text(fee.toFixed(2));

        // set payout
        var payout = ((purchaseAmount - fee) / bitcoinRate);
        $('#summary_payout').text(payout.toFixed(4));
    }

</script>
```

However, I just added a editor template, because I need to expand the original input field:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" style="max-width:200px;" value="@ModelRes.BuyBitcoinStrings.Purchase_Default_Amount" />
```

**View model**:

```
  public class PurchaseViewModel
    {
        public string BitcoinAddress { get; set; }

        [UIHint("InputGroupBox")]
        public int PurchaseAmount { get; set; }
        public string CurrencyChosen { get; set; }

        public bool Accept { get; set; }


        public PurchaseViewModel()
        {
            PurchaseAmount = int.Parse(ModelRes.BuyBitcoinStrings.Purchase_Default_Amount);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does your EditorTemplate code look like as well as how do you call your EditorTemplate?

Comment: The second code snippet (the input field) is the editortemplate, and I call it by making a UIHint as seen int he View model

Comment: `IdFor` should still work in editor templates.

Comment: @AntP It doesn't. IdFor gives something like "PurchaseViewModel_PurchaseAmount". If I don't add an ID in the editor template, there isn't an ID. If I provide a static ID, the IdFor doesn't fetch it